# Searching a default date inside cells

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm retrieving from a SQL DB some information. Sometime happens to receive a blank date that Excel transform in a default date: 01/01/1900

I want to place a blank value instead of default date, but my issue is that all method I tried to search default date don't work.

[image]

I tried these code inside a For cycle, but each time I use it, Excel can't find default date. If I debug and place a stop and try to search normally. Excel says me that is impossible to find 01/01/1900 like it cannot find that date.

```
Set Rng = Cells.Find(What:=CDate(2) _
            , After:=ActiveCell _
            , LookIn:=xlValues _
            , LookAt:=xlWhole _
            , SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
            , SearchDirection:=xlNext _
            , MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then GoTo NextPage
    sRngTrov = Rng.Address
    Range(sRngTrov).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Range(sRngTrov).Value = ""
```

Do you have solution?

Comment: `What:="01/01/1900"`?

Comment: `Set Rng = Cells.Find(What:=CDate(1)`.  VBA dates and Excel dates have a different base (`31-Dec-1899` vs `1-Jan-1900`. This makes things confusing for dates prior to `1-Mar-1900` at which time the stored values are in agreement. You could also use `what:="1/1/1900"`, but this may be less robust, especially if you change your date format for that column.

Comment: If I search "1/1/1900" it do not find it. Seems it cannot recognize it

Answer (score 0):

Please try to format the date with the same style as the cell. I have tested the code on Excel 365 ver. 2309.

```
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=Format(CDate(2), "mm/dd/yyyy") _
```

The default date format maybe different. Double check it with

```
    Debug.Print CDate(2), Format(CDate(2), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still not working. It find nothing and is not possible because I see date.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution put Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat before Find.

```
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
  Set Rng = Cells.Find(What:=Format(CDate(2), "m/d/yyyy") _
            , After:=ActiveCell _
            , LookIn:=xlValues _
            , LookAt:=xlPart _
            , SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
            , SearchDirection:=xlNext _
            , MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=True)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then GoTo Next
```

Comment: The data on screenshot is not in `m/d/yyyy`.